# Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`WW2`

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created tables in MySQL Workbench as shown below :

**LUFEWAFFE table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Luftwaffe(
id_Luftwaffe INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_Rollen INTEGER NOT NULL,
Bezeichnung VARCHAR(255),
id_Tragflaeche INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id_Luftwaffe),
FOREIGN KEY (id_Rollen) REFERENCES Luftwaffe (id_Luftwaffe),
FOREIGN KEY (id_Tragflaeche) REFERENCES Luftwaffe (id_Luftwaffe)
);
```

**TRAGFLAECHE table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tragflaeche(
id_Tragflaeche INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
TragflaecheAnzahl INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY(id_Tragflaeche)
);
```

**INSERT.sql date for LUFTWAFFE**

```
INSERT INTO Luftwaffe (id_Luftwaffe,id_Rollen,Bezeichnung,id_Tragflaeche)
VALUES (1,1 ,"Ar 64",2),
   (4,1 ,"Ar 76",2),
   (5,1,"Ar 197",2),
   (6,1,"Ar 240",1),
   (7,1,"Ar 440",1),
   (8,1,"Fi 98",2),`
```

so when I try to run it:

> Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`WW2`.`Luftwaffe`, CONSTRAINT `Luftwaffe_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_Tragflaeche`) REFERENCES `Luftwaffe` (`id_Luftwaffe`))

I really don't understand what the error is.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In table Luftwaffe you have a fk that references the same table, so id_Tragflaeche in one record references id_Luftwaffe in another record.

You are inserting records into the table with id_Tragflaeche = 2 but you don't have an existing record in that table where id_Luftwaffe = 2, so the FK constraint fails

Comment: Do you mean that I now need reference tbl_Tragfleache with a other tables?

Comment: No. You have created a parent-child relationship within that table (I assume that is what you want to do?), so before you can insert the child record you need to insert the parent record. The ultimate parent record either needs to have a null in its id_Tragflaeche field or to have id_Tragflaeche and id_Luftwaffe having the same value

Comment: Thanks, you've been a big help